# Swift 2.x to Swift 3, Xcode complaining error : Non-optional expression of type 'String' used in a check for optionals

Tags: swift

Migrating from Swift 2.x to Swift 3, I have the warning on my code :

```
let response=NSString(data:data!,encoding: 
String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)
let responseArray:Array=response!.components(separatedBy: "|VCSPACER|")
if let result:String=responseArray[0] {
  if let action:String=responseArray[1] {
    if let datas:String=responseArray[2] {
      .......
    }
  }
}
```

The compiler is warning at line :

```
"if let action:String=responseArray[0]" and line "if let action:String=responseArray[1]" and "line if let datas:String=responseArray[2]"
```

with the message

> "Non-optional expression of type 'String' used in a check for optionals"

It was perfectly working on Swift 2.X but not on Swift 3. How can I change this code to make it work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't use force unwrapping of optionals. The force unwrapping makes it a non-optional value, hence optional binding cannot be used. Moreover, array subscripting does not return an optional value, so rather than trying to use optional binding to check if the array has that many elements, after unwrapping the array, check if it has as many elements as you want to access.

```
if let data = data,
   let responseArray = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)?
                           .components(separatedBy: "|VCSPACER|"),
   responseArray.count > 2 {
    let result = responseArray[0]
    let action = responseArray[1]
    let datas = responseArray[2]
}
```

Comment: Wow ! Just the perfect answer, it works like a charm, thks !